# Read CSV File using c#

Tags: c#, arrays, object, csv

I am working on a project basically the flow as writtien below
Read  2 Csv files
Compare its content row by row and column
identify rows which differ, even by a column
Create a new Csv file to contain the difference

Problems encountered:

1. I cannot read the csv file and store them inj the datatable. I can
   do it with xslx(excel file)  keeps giving error on wrong file
   location

I am suspecting its a connection string error

i was using this String:

```
connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FileDirectory + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR= Yes;FMT = Delimited\"";

Oledbconnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

OleDbDataAdapter Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + Filesheet + "$]", Connection);
```

1. I am using Oledbconnection method, s there a more efficient method?
   without storing would be preferable
2. How do i run the program whereby it will autmatically access the
   file, the files are contain in 2 different folders and compare them
   file by file,as so far i only manage to do a particular file read
3. Do you guys have a better alternative way to solve this problem?

Comment: you want it in c# , why tag java ???

Comment: Do those CSV lines have some kind of primary key, or is it just: `if (file1.Lines[i] != file2.Lines[i]) { file3.WriteLine(file2.Lines[i])}`?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried opening a csv file with a connection string.

CSV files are basically just delimited by rows with \n (or \r\n) and columns by , (or whatever).

So what I personally do is usually open it using a TextReader - and do the following

```
foreach (string row in textString.Split('\n')
{
foreach (string cell in row.Split(',')
{
//One cell at a time

}
}
```

There are libraries for opening csv files, but I find this is the simplest generally.

3.) Well, you'll have to run the code 'twice' using a different file. If they're hard coded use an array - or you can pop up a number of OpenFileDialog to ask the user to pick them

Otherwise having issues understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some good links:

1)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp

2)

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/384247/How-to-read-from-csv-file-using-csharp-net

3)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30705/C-CSV-Import-Export